C# - VSTO Outlook - Folder property is null
I have a little Outlook AddIn and this code
Outlook.NameSpace mapiNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Outlook.CalendarModule calendarModule = (Outlook.CalendarModule)mapiNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar).GetExplorer().NavigationPane.Modules.GetNavigationModule(Outlook.OlNavigationModuleType.olModuleCalendar);
Outlook.NavigationGroups navGroups = calendarModule.NavigationGroups;
Outlook.NavigationGroup source = navGroups["My calendars"];
Outlook.NavigationGroup dest = navGroups["Shared calendars"];

for (int i = source.NavigationFolders.Count; i > 0; i--)
{
    var temp = source.NavigationFolders[i];
    dest.NavigationFolders.Add(source.NavigationFolders[i].Folder);
}

There is a problem in this code, specifically in this line
dest.NavigationFolders.Add(source.NavigationFolders[i].Folder);

because if I manually add calendar to the "My calendars" group in Outlook and run the code, the Folder property of that calendar is null. And of course I will get an error. Any custom calendars have Folder property is null. Please tell me what I need to do to make this code work for any calendar in any way, or use a different code but keep the logic of the code.
